# Set the digits after decimal point

Tags: c++, digits

I have a float number for example 12.12123
Is there a function which would display only number with 2 digits after decimal point
12.12 ?

Here is the code:

```
y1 = ( c1 - (a1 * x)) / b1;
 y2 = ( c2 - a2 * x) / b2;

if (y1 == y2)
  cout << "The same";
```

so if the y1 = 1.001 and the y2 = 1.002 they do not appear as the same.

I tried to add.
            cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
            cout.precision(2);

but it does not seem to help.

Comment: Are you really asking "how to compare two floats so they are the same to 2 decimal points?"

Answer (score 41):

```
/* The C way */
#include <stdio.h>
...
float f = 12.12123f;
printf("%.2f",f);

// The C++ way
#include <iostream>
...
float f = 12.12123f;
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout << f;

// The alternative C++ way
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
...
float f = 12.12123f;
std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << f;
```

In C, the 0 padding is added automatically to the right if there are not enough digits to print. <s>In the C++ examples, instead, this is disabled; to enable this behavior, you should enable the fixed mode on the stream with [`std::fixed`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/fixed/) (or enabling the relevant stream flags with [`std::ios_base::setf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/setf/)).</s>

**Edit**: I remembered wrong; if `fixed` is not set, the `precision` setting says to the stream the *total* number of digits to display, including also the ones before the decimal point. So, in this case I think that the only way is to use the `fixed` mode (examples fixed), which will yield the same behavior of `printf`.

---

#### Links:

- [std::ios_base::precision()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/precision/) reference;
- [std::setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/setprecision/) reference;
- [printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/) reference.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for `printf("%.2f", 12.12123);` or:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << 12.12123;
```

**EDIT:** Question changed, so does the answer.

You never want to use direct equality with floating point, you always compare within [epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) tolerance. Your `epsilon` is just quite large.

Replace `if (y1 == y2)` with `if (abs(y1 - y2) < 0.01)`.

Comment: What it does it output the result in console, but how can I change the value of the variable y1 ?

Comment: y1 = ( c1 - (a1 * x)) / b1;
              cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << y1;

Comment: You can do `y1 = floor(y1 * 100 + 0.5) / 100;` but it would be meaningless: [floating-point precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) cannot represent all decimal numbers, in fact your example `12.12` is approximated as `12.119999999999999` on my platform.

Answer (score 3):

```
double num = 1.4567;
printf("%.2f",num);
```

This would print 1.46

Comment: It's tagged as C++, so he definitely meant using the `iostream` library.

Comment: It was earlier tagged C, later changed to C++ when inconsistency b/w tag and heading was pointed out by MSalters.

Answer (score 2):

```
cout.precision(2);
cout <<f;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main ()
{
   double d = 1.242354345; 
   using namespace std;
   cout << setiosflags(ios::fixed | ios::showpoint)
        << setprecision(2)
        << d; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably asking wrong question. Try following:

```
double diff = fabs(y1-y2);
if(diff < 0.005)
    cout << "Almost same";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
cout.precision(2);
float al = 42.645; //sample
cout << al;
```

Comment: So what's the output look like?