# How to avoid rounding with using of strtold

Tags: c++, double

I tried this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    char *p;
    long double l = strtold("12312.12345", &p);
    std::cout << l << std::endl; //prints 12312.1
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/835bd11fec662c50)

How to avoid that kind of rounding?

Comment: It´s not `strtold`s fault. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923202/set-the-digits-after-decimal-point

Answer (score 1):

Your string is correctly parsed. You can verify it in this way:

```
// Remove the integer part ...
std::cout << (l - 12312) << std::endl;
// ... and you get the fractional part correctly displayed:
// 0.12345
```

So the reported problem is just a matter of output formatting.